# Generic cubic in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb C}^3$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I read that "two generic cubics are not projectively equivalents in $\mathbb P_{\mathbb C}^3$".

I want to know if I understand well the statement.

- Does "generic cubics" means that all the cubics are parametrized by a variety $X$, and that if I take a cubic $C$ there is a Zariski open $U_C \subset X$ such that for all $x \in U_C$, $C_x$ is not projectively equivalent to $C$ ? Or that means that there is a Zariski open $U \subset X$ such that for all $x,y \in U$ the associated cubics $C_x,C_y$ are not projectively equivalents ?
- Does projective equivalent mean a transformation $f : P_{\mathbb C}^3 \to P_{\mathbb C}^3$ such that if $\ell$ is a line then $f(\ell)$ is a line ? (We didn't see such transformation in class, so it's a guess).

Finally, if I want to prove it, what is the best strategy ? Try to find a general equation of a cubic in $P_{\mathbb C}^3$ and come back to linear algebra in $\mathbb C^4$ ?

Thanks in advance. **Please don't give me strong hints or the solution.**

Comment: Maybe counting constants leads to the solution...

Comment: Thanks ! But before searching, I want to be sure to understand exactly what "generical" is and be able to give a rigourous definition of it.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm : I tried to do this exercise. I found that the numbers of parameters for the cubics in $\mathbb P^3$ is $20$, and the numbers of parameters for projective transformations is $14$. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, the space of cubics has $({ 3 + 3 \atop 3}) = 20$ parameters and so is a $\mathbb{P}^{19}$. But the space of projective automorphisms has $\dim PGL(4,k) = 15 = 4 \cdot 4 - 1$ as a variety.

Comment: I counted $\dim GL(4,k) = 15$, here was my mistake, where was I wrong ?

Comment: For me there is $16$ parameters for the space of matrix $4 \times 4$, the condition of "being invertible" delete one parameters, and the projectivity delete one other.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Ok I understood my mistake. $GL_n(k)$ is not a variety but a dense open of $A_k^{n^2}$, so it does not change the dimension. Thanks again !